# Privileges starting from a certain reputation

Tags: support

I couldnt find a list, where it shows, which privileges you get from the moment you reach what reputation.

Where do I have to search and why is it so hard to find?

I tried the search in the help section searching for "privileges" and for "rebutation" doesn't give the answer

---

### update:

The Privileges-explanation is really far down at the page and it is not findeable over the search functionality:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go click on '[help](https://security.stackexchange.com/help)' in the top bar, go to 'help center' in the drop down menu.

On that page, there is a heading marked '[privileges](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)' which will give you exactly what you want.

I'm not sure how much easier they could make it. Not sure why the search function doesn't find it, but if you read the help page, it should be fairly obvious. Perhaps not on a small screen.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link to the [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) from the “help” menu in the top bar. Search for the word “privilege” on that page: it appears in the link [View a full list of privileges you can earn](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), which is exactly what you're asking for: a list of privileges and their reputation requirements.

The help center home screen also contains a “Search help pages” box near the middle of the page (not to be confused with the main site search box at the top right). If you search for “privileges” there, you get a list of specific pages; each page is indicated as being in a certain section and most of the hits are from the [Privileges](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) section, which is again that list of privileges. If you search for “reputation”, the second hit is [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), the first paragraph of which explains how reputation grants [privileges](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), again linked to that list privileges.

I don't think there's any call for more methods to find that page.

Comment: Maybe the color of the navigation in the help centre on the right in red is bad. Cause it looks like an add-block that the eye is used to ignore